# Cluster groups continuously instead of discrete - python

Tags: pandas, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to cluster a group of points in a probabilistic manner. Using below, I have a single set of xy points, which are recorded in `X` and `Y`. I want to cluster into groups using a reference point, which is displayed in `X2` and `Y2`.

With the help of an answer the current approach is to measure the distance from the reference point and group using k-means. Although, it provides a method to cluster using the reference point, the hard cutoff and adherence to *k* clusters makes it somewhat unsuitable when dealing with numerous datasets. For instance, the number of clusters needed for this example is probably 3. But a separate example may different. I'd have to manually go through and alter *k* every time.

Given the non-probabilistic nature of k-means a separate option could be `GMM`. Is it possible to account for the reference point when modelling? If I attach the output below the underlying model isn't clustering as I'm hoping for.

If I look at the probability each point is within a group it's not clustered as I'd hoped. With this I run into the same problem with manually altering the amount of components. Because the points are distributed randomly, using “AIC” or “BIC” to select the appropriate number of clusters doesn't work. There is no optimal number.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

df = pd.DataFrame({                                   
    'X' : [-1.0,-1.0,0.5,0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,0.0,-2.5,2.0,8.0,-10.5,15.0,-20.0,-32.0,-20.0,-20.0,-10.0,20.5,0.0,20.0,-30.0,-15.0,20.0,-15.0,-10.0],
    'Y' : [0.0,1.0,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.0,1.0,4.0,5.0,-3.5,-2.0,-8.0,-0.5,-10.5,-20.5,0.0,16.0,-15.0,5.0,13.5,20.0,-20.0,2.0,-17.5,-15,19.0,20.0],     
    'X2' : [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
    'Y2' : [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],           
    })
```

[image]

k-means:

```
df['distance'] = np.sqrt(df['X']**2 + df['Y']**2)
df['distance'] = np.sqrt((df['X2'] - df['Y2'])**2 + (df['BallY'] - df['y_post'])**2)

model = KMeans(n_clusters = 2) 

model_data = np.array([df['distance'].values, np.zeros(df.shape[0])])
model.fit(model_data.T) 
df['group'] = model.labels_ 

plt.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], c = model.labels_, cmap = 'bwr', marker = 'o', s = 5)
plt.scatter(df['X2'], df['Y2'], c ='k', marker = 'o', s = 5)
```

[image]

GMM:

```
Y_sklearn = df[['X','Y']].values

gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type='diag', random_state=42)
gmm.fit(Y_sklearn)
labels = gmm.predict(Y_sklearn)
df['group'] = labels
plt.scatter(Y_sklearn[:, 0], Y_sklearn[:, 1], c=labels, s=5, cmap='viridis');
plt.scatter(df['X2'], df['Y2'], c='red', marker = 'x', edgecolor = 'k', s = 5, zorder = 10)

proba = pd.DataFrame(gmm.predict_proba(Y_sklearn).round(2)).reset_index(drop = True)
df_pred = pd.concat([df, proba], axis = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean density estimation? You can model your data as a Gaussian Mixture and then get a probability of a point to belong to the mixture. You can use `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` for that. By changing number of components you can control how many clusters you will have. The metric to cluster on is Euclidian distance from the reference point. So the GMM model will provide you with prediction of which cluster the data point should be classified to.

Since your metric is 1d, you will get a set of Gaussian distributions, i.e. a set of means and variances. So you can easily calculate the probability of any point to be in certain cluster, just by calculating how far it is from the reference point and put the value in the normal distribution pdf formula.

To make image more clear, I'm changing the reference point to (-5, 5) and select number of clusters = 4. In order to get the best number of clusters, use some metric that minimizes total variance and penalizes growth of number of mixtures. For example `argmin(model.covariances_.sum()*num_clusters)`

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
df = pd.DataFrame({                                   
    'X' : [-1.0,-1.0,0.5,0.0,0.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,0.0,-2.5,2.0,8.0,-10.5,15.0,-20.0,-32.0,-20.0,-20.0,-10.0,20.5,0.0,20.0,-30.0,-15.0,20.0,-15.0,-10.0],
    'Y' : [0.0,1.0,-0.5,0.5,-0.5,0.0,1.0,4.0,5.0,-3.5,-2.0,-8.0,-0.5,-10.5,-20.5,0.0,16.0,-15.0,5.0,13.5,20.0,-20.0,2.0,-17.5,-15,19.0,20.0],     
    })

ref_X, ref_Y = -5, 5
dist  = np.sqrt((df.X-ref_X)**2 + (df.Y-ref_Y)**2)

n_mix = 4
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_mix)
model = gmm.fit(dist.values.reshape(-1,1))
x = np.linspace(-35., 35.)
y = np.linspace(-30., 30.)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
XX = np.sqrt((X.ravel() - ref_X)**2 + (Y.ravel() - ref_Y)**2)
Z = model.score_samples(XX.reshape(-1,1))
Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)

# plot grid points probabilities
plt.set_cmap('plasma')
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 40)
plt.scatter(df.X, df.Y, c=model.predict(dist.values.reshape(-1,1)), edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

You can read more [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_pdf.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-mixture-plot-gmm-pdf-py) and [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.12-gaussian-mixtures.html)

P.S. `score_samples()` returns log likelihoods, use `exp()` to convert to probability

Comment: I don't mind this but what if I have multiple components? Is it also possible to model of a reference point? I've updated my question. This has helped though.

Comment: Sure. I will update the answer to make the point more clear.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, if you want to define clusters as "regions where points are close to each other", you should use [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#dbscan).
This clustering algorithm finds clusters by looking at regions where points are close to each other (i.e. dense regions), and are separated from other clusters by regions where points are less dense.
This algorithm can categorize points as noise (outliers). Outliers are labelled -1.
They are points that do not belong to any cluster.

Here is some code to perform DBSCAN clustering, and to insert the cluster labels as a new categorical column in the original `Y_sklearn` DataFrame. It also prints how many clusters and how many outliers are found.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN


Y_sklearn = df.loc[:, ["X", "Y"]].copy()
n_points = Y_sklearn.shape[0]

dbs = DBSCAN()
labels_clusters = dbs.fit_predict(Y_sklearn)

#Number of found clusters (outliers are not considered a cluster).
n_clusters = labels_clusters.max() + 1
print(f"DBSCAN found {n_clusters} clusters in dataset with {n_points} points.")

#Number of found outliers (possibly no outliers found).
n_outliers = np.count_nonzero((labels_clusters == -1))
if n_outliers:
    print(f"{n_outliers} outliers were found.\n")
else:
    print(f"No outliers were found.\n")

#Add cluster labels as a new column to original DataFrame.
Y_sklearn["cluster"] = labels_clusters
#Setting `cluster` column to Categorical dtype makes seaborn function properly treat
#cluster labels as categorical, and not numerical.
Y_sklearn["cluster"] = Y_sklearn["cluster"].astype("category")
```

If you want to plot the results, I suggest you use Seaborn. Here is some code to plot the points of `Y_sklearn` DataFrame, and color them by the cluster they belong to. I also define a new color palette, which is just the default Seaborn color palette, but where outliers (with label -1) will be in black.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


name_palette = "tab10"
palette = sns.color_palette(name_palette)
if n_outliers:
    color_outliers = "black"
    palette.insert(0, color_outliers)
else:
    pass
sns.set_palette(palette)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=Y_sklearn,
                x="X",
                y="Y",
                hue="cluster",
                ax=ax,
                )
```

Using default hyperparameters, the DBSCAN algorithm finds no cluster in the data you provided: all points are considered outliers, because there is no region where points are significantly more dense. Is that your whole dataset, or is it just a sample? If it is a sample, the whole dataset will have much more points, and DBSCAN will certainly find some high density regions.
Or you can try tweaking the hyperparameters, `min_samples` and `eps` in particular. If you want to "force" the algorithm to find more clusters, you can decrease `min_samples` (default is 5), or increase `eps` (default is 0.5). Of course, the optimal hyperparamete values depends on the specific dataset, but default values are considered quite good for DBSCAN. So, if the algorithm considers all points in your dataset to be outliers, it means that there are no "natural" clusters!

Answer (score 2):

Taking your centre point of 0,0 we can calculate the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) from this point to all points in your df.

```py
df['distance'] = np.sqrt(df['X']**2 + df['Y']**2)
```

If you have a centre point other than zero it would be:

```py
df['distance'] = np.sqrt((centre_point_x - df['X'])**2 + (centre_point_y - df['Y'])**2)
```

Using your data and chart as before, we can plot this and see the distance metric increasing as we move away from the centre.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,6))

ax.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], c = df['distance'], cmap = 'viridis', marker = 'o', s = 30)

ax.set_xlim([-35, 35])
ax.set_ylim([-35, 35])

plt.show()
```

[image: euclidean distance visualised]

### K-means

We can now use this distance data and use it to calculate K-means clusters as you did before, but this time using the distance data and an array of zeros (zeros because this k-means requires a 2d-array but we only want to split the 1d aray of dimensional data. So the zeros act as 'filler'

```py
model = KMeans(n_clusters = 2) #choose how many clusters
# create this 2d array for the KMeans model
model_data = np.array([df['distance'].values, np.zeros(df.shape[0])])
model.fit(model_data.T) # transformed array because the above code produces
# data with 27 columns and 2 rows but we want it the other way round
df['group'] = model.labels_ # put the labels into the dataframe
```

Then we can plot the results

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,6))

ax.scatter(df['X'], df['Y'], c = df['group'], cmap = 'viridis', marker = 'o', s = 30)

ax.set_xlim([-35, 35])
ax.set_ylim([-35, 35])

plt.show()
```

[image: k-means results]

With three clusters we get the following result:

[image: results for three clusters]

### Other clustering methods

Check out [SKlearn's clustering page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) for more options. I experimented with DBSCAN with some good results but it depends on what you are trying to achieve exactly. Check out the table underneath their example charts to see how they each compare.

Comment: Thanks. The cluster of points will vary so I'm hoping to include some form of probabilistic model. 3 components makes visual sense in this example but I have instances where other components are appropriate. I'm hoping to handle this issue autonomously.

Comment: To calculate the 'best' number of clusters you can do it with a few different methods. This can be written in to your code so no manual tweaking is necessary. See this [Real Python k-means page](https://realpython.com/k-means-clustering-python/#choosing-the-appropriate-number-of-clusters) for how to do it.

Comment: Yeh I think DBSCAN is the best bet.